# MS SQL Server 2012 with Visual Studio 2010 and Entity Framework compatibility

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2012

I need your help to know if I can use Visual Studio 2010 and its Entity Framework 4 with a remote instance of SQL Server 2012?

I've developed a data project using VS 2010 and EF4 but my company only offers SQL Server 2012 for remote servers.

- Can Visual Studio data explorer detect the new created data base under SQL Server 2012?
- Should I create a new EMDX model based on the new DB or the whole project will be updated if I update the DataSource?
- Is there any other compatibility issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Can Visual Studio data explorer detect the new created data base
  under SQL Server 2012?

It will look at whatever database is referenced in the connection string, as long as the correct ports are open on any firewalls between the machine the app is running on and the machine hosting the database. It doesn't go out looking about for new databases. EF does work with SQL Server 2012.

- Should I create a new EMDX model based on the new DB or the whole
  project will be updated if I update the DataSource?

If the database in the connection string doesn't match what the EF model expects the app will throw errors at runtime. In VS you can tell the model to update itself to match the database it is pointed at. It won't happen automatically.

My projects build the model from my dev database, then run in production against the production database which is on a totally different server (and in a different domain as well). No problems as long as I make sure that updated which change the db (and hence the model) are applied to the production db as we roll out a new version of the client.

- Is there any other compatibility issues?

Given that both are MS products/components, I'll bet that MS worked pretty hard to ensure that there aren't. I have never seen any, in any case.